# The meet of two dominant permutations in weak order of $S_n$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups, pattern-avoidance

A permutation is called dominant if its Lehmer code is a partition, or equivalently if it avoids the pattern $132$.

I can prove that given a permutation $v\in S_n$, there is a unique dominant permutation $\mu(v)$ such that $v\leq_R \mu(v)$ (where $\leq_R$ denotes right weak order) and if $\mu$ is any other dominant permutation such that $v\leq_R \mu$ then $\mu(v)\leq_R \mu$.

In particular, this implies that the meet of two dominant permutations in the weak order lattice is itself a dominant permutation.

I'm not really into the whole pattern avoidance aspect of permutations, nor have I much knowledge of what's going on in the study of weak order on Coxeter groups. Does anyone care that the meet of two $132$-avoiding permutations is itself a $132$-avoiding permutation?

In addition to this, dominant permutations end up being extremely important in Schubert calculus. Does anyone have any references that study their properties?

Comment: Is it not just the Tamari lattice you get this way? See in particular Theorem 9.6 of https://www.math.miami.edu/~wachs/papers/nonpure2.pdf.

Comment: @SamHopkins If the map in Proposition 9.10 is order-preserving, then yes, the dominant permutations form a lattice isomorphic to the Tamari lattice. I'm not sure that the join of two dominant permutations in weak order is dominant, though, so it may not be a sublattice of $S_n$ in weak order. I couldn't find a counterexample with a cursory search.

Comment: This is me being lazy and not looking up all the details, but $x$ is $132$ avoiding if and only if $w_0 x$ is $312$-avoiding if and only if $w_0 x$ is $c$-sortable for $c = s_1 s_2 \cdots s_{n-1}$. (See Section 4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507186 .) The $c$-sortable elements form a sublattice (see Theorem 1.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512339 ) and, for $c=s_1 s_2 \cdots s_{n-1}$ or $= s_{n-1} s_{n-2} \cdots s_2 s_1$, it is the Tamari lattice.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Since $w_0$ reverses weak order, I guess that means the dominant permutations form a sublattice as well. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Anyway, this raises even more questions. Is $\mu(u\vee v)=\mu(u)\vee\mu(v)$? That would be cool. Then $\mu: S_n\to S_n$ would be a lattice homomorphism of $S_n$ onto the dominant permutations.

Comment: Yes, this should be the map that Reading calls $\pi_c^{\uparrow}$ (and the map to $312$-avoiding should be $\pi^c_{\downarrow}$). Both $\pi^{\uparrow}$ and $\pi_{\downarrow}$ are lattice homomorphisms. You basically want to read Reading's papers.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Glad I asked this question then, I would've wasted time developing parts of this theory when someone has already done it in far greater generality! It sort of leads to the question of whether my results involving Schubert polynomials for dominant permutations can be generalized to type $B$, since we have a Pieri formula for the flag manifold available there. What would be required is that the Schubert classes for $\pi^\uparrow_c$ elements are products of elementary Schubert classes.